# How do I use WHERE after inserting variables in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to update a specific row using its OID. I don't how to use UPDATE in a way that it grabs the variable updatednumber to UPDATE only the specific row I want.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

test = 12

def subtract():
    query = ("SELECT * FROM test WHERE oid = 2") 
    c.execute(query)
    record = c.fetchone()
    r = record[1]
    updatednumber = (test - r)



def subtract1():
    c.execute("""UPDATE products SET qty = (:paid),
              {
              
              'tpaid': updatednumber
              
              }
              WHERE oid = 2""")

subtract()
subtract1()
```

When I run this, it tells me that { is an unrecognized token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax is wrong:

```
c.execute("""UPDATE products SET qty = (:paid),
          {
           
          'tpaid': updatednumber
              
          }
          WHERE oid = 2""")
```

since you've embedded the dictionary inside the query string; it should be the second parameter to `execute()`. So do this instead:

```
c.execute("UPDATE products SET qty = :paid WHERE oid = :oid", {'paid': updatednumber, 'oid': 2})
```